# Finding $\mathbb{P}(X_4 > \max (X_1,X_2) > X_3)$ and $\mathbb{P}(\min(X_6,X_7,X_8) > \max (X_1,X_2,...,X_5)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Lately I have stumbled upon the following problem:

> A random sample of size $8$ is taken from a distribution admitting a continuous density function $f(.)$. Then find
>
> 1. $\mathbb{P}(X_4 > \max (X_1,X_2) > X_3)$
> 2. $\mathbb{P}(\min(X_6,X_7,X_8) > \max (X_1,X_2,...,X_5)$

My attempt has been like this:

For part 1, there are basically $4!=24$ equally likely events:
$$(X_1>X_2>X_3>X_4), (X_1>X_2>X_4>X_3),... (X_4>X_3>X_2>X_1)$$ each with probability $\frac{1}{24}$. Now the event in part 1 correspond to only $4$ of those $24$ events,namely $$(X_4>X_1>X_2>X_3), (X_4>X_2>X_1>X_3), (X_4>X_2>X_3>X_1), (X_4>X_1>X_3>X_2)$$ .
So $\mathbb{P}(X_4 >\max (X_1,X_2) > X_3)= \frac{4}{24}=\frac{1}{6}$

If my reasoning in part **1** is correct,then by a similar argument the answer of part **2** that I got is $ \frac{3! × 5!}{8!}$.

Is this the correct approach and have I got  the right answer for both parts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems correct, however, you should point out why u didn't consider events when at least two variables are equal ( I know it isn't important due to their probabilities).

Comment: @DominikKutek because the random variables are of continuous type. But are you sure my answer for part 2 is also correct?

Comment: Yes, after getting rid of events with probability $0$, we're left with $8!$ events of type $X_1 < ... < X_8$. In order for $\min(X_6,X_7,X_8) > \max(X_1,...X_5)$ to happen, variables $X_6,X_7,X_8$ must be placed before the rest (in any order). So $3!$ ways. And variables $X_1,...,X_5$ are placed after those $3$, again in any order, so $5!$ ways. That gives us $\frac{3!\cdot 5!}{8!}$

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me!

Comment: You're welcome!